# Extract attachment from selected mail from outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

Here I'm going to create an Outlook add in which extracts an attachment from Outlook using C#.

I place a button on Outlook using add ins and on `on_click` event, I called this method below; code is working fine. It's extracting all attachments which are placed in inbox of Outlook, but I want only attachment which I select from mouse.

Can any one help me to out this issue?

```
private void ThisApplication_NewMail()
{
  Outlook.MAPIFolder inBox = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
  Outlook.Items inBoxItems = inBox.Items;
  Outlook.MailItem newEmail = null;
  //inBoxItems = inBoxItems.Restrict("[Unread] = true");
  try
  {
    foreach (object collectionItem in inBoxItems)
    {
      newEmail = collectionItem as Outlook.MailItem;
      if (newEmail != null)
      {
        if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)
        {
          for (int i = 1; i <= newEmail.Attachments.Count; i++)
          {
            newEmail.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(@"C:\TestFileSave\" +
                                newEmail.Attachments[i].FileName);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    string errorInfo = (string)ex.Message.Substring(0, 11);
    if (errorInfo == "Cannot save")
    {
      System.Windows .Forms . MessageBox.Show(@"Create Folder C:\TestFileSave");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi John Willemse. what u edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a  **FormRegion** control and insert it into your outlook message window.

Then when you click a message on your inbox you can get the message class with:

```
private void FormRegionMessageClassArchivadoFactory_FormRegionInitializing(object sender, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionInitializingEventArgs e)
            {

                Outlook.MailItem item = (Outlook.MailItem)e.OutlookItem;     
                 if (item.Attachments.Count > 0)
                 {
                                int attachRestantes = item.Attachments.Count;

                                for (int j = attachRestantes; j >=1; j--)
                                {
                                    //get attachments
                                }           

                 }     
            }
```

**EDIT:**

To get the attachment content as byte use the following code.

```
 //microsoft schema to get the attachment content
 private string AttachSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102";

  Outlook.PropertyAccessor pacc = item.Attachments[j].PropertyAccessor;
  byte[] filebyte = (byte[])pacc.GetProperty(AttachSchema);
```

Comment: It's not working in outlook 2007. In outlook 2010 it's working fine.@CarlosLanderas

Answer (score 0):

I would look at hooking into the Explorer.Selection change event:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869813.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is your issue about finding the selected email, or selecting an attachment in the current email ?

We extract the selected emails in the mailbox, then prompt the user to select the attachments to save in a custom form. Here is our routine to extract the email user selection.

```
Outlook.Explorer curExplorer = OutlookApplication.ActiveExplorer();
Outlook.NameSpace curNameSpace = OutlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder curFolder = curExplorer.CurrentFolder;
if (curExplorer.Selection != null && curExplorer.Selection.Count > 0)
{
    // get mails
    _lstMailItems = new List<Outlook.MailItem>();
    try
    {
        foreach (Outlook.MailItem curMailItem in curExplorer.Selection)
        {
            // modification on mail items in plugin are repercuted in Outlook
            _lstMailItems.Add(curMailItem);
        }
    }
    catch (COMException exc)
    {
        // log, selected item is not an email.
    }
}
```